# Return 0 for no rows returned using SUM and IIF in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum, iif

I am looking for a way to return **0** as result for a SQL Query in MS Access when no rows are returned. Following is my query:

```
SELECT SUM(IIF(TotalCount =  null, 0, TotalCount)) AS MailCount  FROM MailReport WHERE [SendDate]=#2/12/2013# and MailerID=1
```

Here the Column `TotalCount` is number type and works fine for a query that returns some result. But in case for example date `2/13/2013` has no records, it would simply return a `blank` row that is nither `0` nor `null`. How do I return a 0 for this row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  SUM(IIF([SendDate]=#2/12/2013# AND MailerID = 1, IIF(TotalCount =  null, 0, TotalCount), 0)) AS MailCount  
FROM    MailReport
```

Comment: thanks that's really genius idea. And, that's perfectly what I needed. Cheers.....:)

Comment: The OP is using MS Access, so you could also use Nz : `SELECT Nz(SUM(IIF(TotalCount =  null, 0, TotalCount)),0)` ( http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/nz-function-HA001228890.aspx )

Comment: @Remou thanks. to be honest i am not totally familiar with builtin functions of ms access. Thank you `:)`